# C# Regexcollection between special characters

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying use regex to parse the values `903001`,`343001`,`343491` in the following input:

```
"contact_value":"903001" other random
"contact_value":"343001" random information
"contact_value":"343491" more random
```

I used the following in c# but it returns "contact_value":"903001"

```
MatchCollection numMatch = Regex.Matches(input, @"contact_value\"":\"".*"\""");
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The regex could be as simple as

```
@"\d+"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `@` with strings (e.g. @"string"), escape characters are not processed. In those strings, you use `""` instead of `\"` to represent double quotes. Try this regex:

```
var regex = @"contact_value"":""(\d+)"""
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
string input = "\"contact_value\":\"1234567890\"" ;
Regex rx = new Regex( @"^\s*""contact_value""\s*:\s*""(?<value>\d+)""\s*$" ) ;
Match m = rx.Match( input ) ;
if ( !m.Success )
{
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid");
}
else
{
    string value = m.Groups["value"].Value ;
    int n = int.Parse(value) ;
    Console.WriteLine( "The contact_value is {0}",n) ;
}
```

[And read up on how to use regular expressions]